# Sticky Header Animation Bouncing on Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I'm using a modified version of the [On-Scroll Animate Header from codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/06/on-scroll-animated-header/), and I'm having an issue with the menu bouncing up and down on scroll near the top.

This is my modified code:

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

var docElem = document.documentElement,
    didScroll = false,
changeHeaderOn = 160;

function init() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}

function scrollPage() {
var sy = scrollY();
    if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
  $('body > header').addClass('header--sticky');
    }   else {
        $('body > header').removeClass('header--sticky');
    }
    didScroll = false;
}

function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
}

init();

})();
```

The code works fine in general, however, when I scroll one "click" on my mouse from the top position (page load default), the header seems to be sitting in limbo and bouncing back and forth between adding and removing the class that I have. Does anyone have any suggestions on what changes I need to make to get this to work properly?

A working demo can be found at [www.linkup.co.nz/preview/](https://www.linkup.co.nz/preview/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when the header becomes sticky, the header is no longer included in the page height, and there is no longer scrolled down 160 pixels. Here it is the problem step by step.

1. The page is scrolled down 200px
2. The header becomes sticky and its height is subtracted from the page.
3. The page is now only scrolled down 141 pixels.
4. The header becomes unsticky.
5. Repeat.

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Change `changeHeaderOn = 160;` to `changeHeaderOn = 200;` (There'll still be a "switchy" state, but less likely to happen.)
2. Add a placeholder to not change the page's height (untested)

```js
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

  var docElem = document.documentElement,
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 160;

  function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
      if (!didScroll) {
        didScroll = true;
        setTimeout(scrollPage, 250);
      }
    }, false);
  }

  function scrollPage() {
    var sy = scrollY(),
      $header = $('body > header');
    if (sy >= changeHeaderOn) {

      // Add space where the header used to be
      var $headerPlaceholder = $('<div class="js-header-placeholder">').height($header.outerHeight);
      $header.before($headerPlaceholder)

      // Now let the header become sticky
      $header.addClass('header--sticky');
    } else {
      $header.removeClass('header--sticky');
      $('.js-header-placeholder').remove();
    }
    didScroll = false;
  }

  function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
  }

  init();

})();
```

3. Add padding on top to not change the page's height (untested)

```js
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

  var docElem = document.documentElement,
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 160;

  function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
      if (!didScroll) {
        didScroll = true;
        setTimeout(scrollPage, 250);
      }
    }, false);
  }

  function scrollPage() {
    var sy = scrollY(),
      $header = $('body > header');
    if (sy >= changeHeaderOn) {

      // Add space where the header used to be
      $('body').css('padding-top', $header.outerHeight);

      // Now let the header become sticky
      $header.addClass('header--sticky');
    } else {
      $header.removeClass('header--sticky');
      
      $('body').css('padding-top', '');
    }
    didScroll = false;
  }

  function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
  }

  init();

})();
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I was waiting for you to post the rest of your answer and forgot to come back. I ended up going with the 200 option and it worked perfectly!

Comment: That's a good point, @dpDesignz. Next time, I add a comment to tell you. Also, your welcome and God bless :)